JPA delete parent through child in in ManyToOne relationship using CascadeType.all
I want to delete the parent if the child gets deleted while the parent doesn't have any other children.
If i use CascadeType.ALL i get a foreign key error when attempting to delete a child while more than one child exists.
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Parent parent;
}

@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}

If i try to delete a child i will get an error because it attempts to delete a parent which still has other children pointing to it.
